# Алгоритм слепой подписи RSA. Несоответствующие значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

При написании кода столкнулся с проблемой, что шифруемый текст не совпадает с расшифрованными данными. Не могу выяснить причину проблемы.

(значение ss1 должно быть как после перевода текста в ASCII)

````
# source: https://habr.com/ru/post/594925/
import math

p = 233
r = 439
q = 1337
e = 11
fn = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
d = 1

while (d * e) % fn != 1:
    d += 1
print('d = ', d)

e = 11  # exponent, open key 2
N = p * q  # open key 1

print('N = ', N, 'F(n) = ', fn)


msg = ('input("Enter your message: ")')
ascii_values = []
m1 = []
s1 = []
ss1 = []
fn = (p - 1) * (q - 1)


def ascii_enc(message):
    for character in message:
        ascii_values.append(ord(character))
    return ascii_values


(ascii_enc(msg))
print('ASCII result:', ascii_values, 'Length = ', len(ascii_values))

for character in range(len(ascii_values)):  # aвтор сообщения вычисляет произведение сообщения и маскирующего фактора
    m = (ascii_values[character] * (r ** e)) % N
    m1.append(m)

print("m'"" = ", m1)

for i in range(len(m1)):  # подписывающий орган вычисляет слепую подпись
    s = (m1[i] ** d) % N
    s1.append(s)

print("s'"" = ", s1)

for i in range(len(s1)):  # s' отправляется обратно автору сообщения, который затем может удалить
    ss = ((s1[i]) * (r**(-1))) % N  # маскирующий фактор, чтобы выявить s, действительную подпись RSA для m
    ss1.append(ss)


print("s = ", ss1) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых,
1337 – составное число, значит функция Эйлера вычислена неправильно, и все дальнейшие вычисления не работают.

Во-вторых,

r<sup>-1</sup> (mod N)

это не просто

```
r**-1 % N
```

В общем случае, его можно вычислить, например, с помощью расширенного алгоритма Евклида.

Но так как у вас

r ≡ r<sup>ed</sup> (mod N)

и r взаимно простое с N, получается

r<sup>-1</sup> ≡ r<sup>ed-2</sup> (mod N)

т.е.

```py
r_inv = pow(r, e * d - 2, N)
```

Правда d доступна только подписывающему органу, так что в реальной ситуации так сделать не выйдет. Также можно воспользоваться теоремой Эйлера (правда, тут та же ситуация)

```py
r_inv = pow(r, fn - 1, N)
```

Ну и в python 3.8+ функция `pow` сама умеет находить обратные значения по модулю (грубо говоря, возводить в отрицательную степень по модулю), если это возможно, так что

```py
r_inv = pow(r, -1, N)
```

Ну либо можете воспользоваться перебором, как делаете в случае `d`. Само собой, на настоящих ключах перебор займет околобесконечное время.

Замените `r**-1` на `r_inv` – приблизитесь на шаг к результату.

В-третьих, `ss1` **не** должно быть как после перевода в ASCII, это значение подписи, а не само подписываемое значение

Для того, чтобы получить оригинал все нужно возвести в степень `e` по модулю `N`

```py
print([pow(x, e, N) for x in ss1])
```